# Display {{ }} Jade-Angular-React-Vue

Tags: angularjs, pug, vue.js

I'm trying to add {{}} for angular {{}} to Jade. 
In html you do this

```
 <p>{{ whatever  }}</p>
```

In jade, my understanding was:

```
p  {{ whatever }}
```

But it is not working. Any insight on how to add the double curly brackets to Jade so it display the information from Angular (react or vue, they all work the same way)

I tried

```
p {{ }}

p
  |{{ }}

p
= {{ }}
```

Any Jade ninja out there?

Comment: Weird, I've been using `p {{vueData}}`, it works fine. Maybe post your compilation error here?

Comment: I will try again and get back to you later on today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference your vue files in jade (in express app, layout.jade) after block contents not inside the body tag:

```
body
//not here
block content
script(src="./javascripts/vueapp.js")
```

Answer (score 0):

In `"jade": "1.9.2"`, if you have following in JS:

```
res.render('blog_edit', {title: 'edit your blog', posts: "something"});
```

In template, you can use either of follwing:

```
#{locals.posts}
```

or

```
#{posts}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not trying to use interpolation which to pass from express to jade.

Comment: I'm trying to use what Angular, React and VueJS use which the double {{ }}

Comment: @Marco Angular does [interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) of variable using {{}}.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the double curly bracket not the single one. Your answer is showing the single bracket, right? Or did you mean to type double curly brackets?

Comment: What did I miss? It seems I missed your your and I'm trying to add double {{}} not the single {}....

Comment: this is how [interpolation](https://codepen.io/pixelass/post/let-us-jade-3-interpolation-and-javascript#string-interpolation-0) works in Jade.

Comment: Can I use the single {} for angular?I didn't see that in any of their documents. That is why I'm asking. I'm new to the client front frameworks so forgive my lack of proper explanation...

Comment: No, Syntax for Jade is using #{}, while for angularJs/VueJs it is {{}}.

Comment: Thank you. Then I can't use jade. I'll have to use html file with res.sendFile(xx.html) in express.  PUG team needs to consider this in futuure releases.

Comment: @Marco What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I have an api in express. One page is required to be no refresh using angular, react or vue. I know Vue and built the page in html to test. then I thought to use PUG as I think it is more efficient but alas, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check,

1. did you specified ng-controller? if not, you should.

   `body(ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main")`
2. does your controller has that value? if not, you can create test code.

   `$scope.test = "test"`
   `p {{ test }}`
3. did you include angular.js?

   `script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js")`
4. did you correctly create angular app?

   `var app = angular.module('myApp');
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.test = "test";
    }`
5. did you include your angluar app?

   `script(src="javascripts/myApp.js")`
6. {{ }} should not have space between { and {.

If you still have a problem let me know.

Comment: HTML runs the app ok. So it is not a reference issue. It is when I try to display the data entered by a form on the page. I will post code later on today. It is the {{vue data entered in a form}} that doesn't display the data. The form and everything else is working fine in the html

Comment: Did you connect data form with **ng-model**?

Comment: It was my mistake. I referenced the app.js before block contents but it should be after it.

Comment: body
     
    block content
    script(src="./javascripts/vueapp.js")

Comment: Thank you for your help. When you said you use {{}} all the time, made me question my js files reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative. Just put ng-bind, like this:

```
div(ng-app="" ng-init="name=' Rodrigo'")
        p My name is
            span(ng-bind="name")
```

Jade is no longer Jade hahaha, now it's Pug.js
I know we are in 2018, but this is my small contribution